# After changing Docker Root Directory: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine

Tags: docker, containers

After changing the default Docker Root Directory `/var/lib/docker` by adding my new directory `--data-root /media/abdelaziz/1E6AFBDE6AFBB09F1/installation/docker` to the `docker.service` file:

1- I reloaded the `daemon-reload` file with  `systemctl daemon-reload`

2- Moved my containers created previously at `/var/lib/docker` to my new destination

3- Restarting the docker service with : `systemctl restart docker`

**BUT**

The service didn't start and I got this message:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And `systemctl status docker.service` returned:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since ر 2020-05-20 14:46:43 CET; 7min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 23842 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --data-root /media/abdelaziz/1E6AFBDE6AFBB09F1/insta
 Main PID: 23842 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ماي 20 14:46:41 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
ماي 20 14:46:41 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
ماي 20 14:46:41 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ماي 20 14:46:43 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
ماي 20 14:46:43 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
ماي 20 14:46:43 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
ماي 20 14:46:43 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
ماي 20 14:46:43 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
ماي 20 14:46:43 abdelaziz-VPCEH3U1E systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

Does anyone have any idea about what should I do?

Comment: Try to run it in root terminal and see what error you see in log `/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --data-root /media/abdelaziz/1E6AFBDE6AFBB09F1/installation/docker`

Comment: This what it returned:
`INFO[2020-05-20T17:29:42.509296103+01:00] Starting up                                  
failed to load listeners: no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd
`

Comment: Try adding a `--debug` flag also to the command and see if the log changes

Comment: Nothing changed!

Comment: After unmounting and mounting the new directory partition docker starts normally but i am losing all my images and containers and when i tried to check what is the docker root directory by using `docker info | grep root` I only get `WARNING: No swap limit support`! any idea?

Comment: Are you using some external hard drive to keep docker data?

Comment: Not external, but in a separate partition from where ubuntu is installed.

Comment: By applying this solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408955/413634 the warning was removed but then no root directory is shown with: `docker info | root`